# Linux Command line tool to work with netmasks / CIDR notation

Tags: linux, networking, command-line-interface, subnet, cidr

I'm terrible at working out network subnets in my head. Is there some command line tool for linux (ubuntu packages a plus), that lets me put in `255.255.255.224` and it'll tell me that is a `/27`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

[ipcalc](http://www.jodies.de/ipcalc) can do this, for example:

```
[kbrandt@kbrandt-opadmin: ~] ipcalc 192.168.1.1/24                 
Address:   192.168.1.1          11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000001
Netmask:   255.255.255.0 = 24   11111111.11111111.11111111. 00000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.255            00000000.00000000.00000000. 11111111
=>
Network:   192.168.1.0/24       11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000000
HostMin:   192.168.1.1          11000000.10101000.00000001. 00000001
HostMax:   192.168.1.254        11000000.10101000.00000001. 11111110
Broadcast: 192.168.1.255        11000000.10101000.00000001. 11111111
Hosts/Net: 254                   Class C, Private Internet
```

if you entered a subnet mask instead of CIDR, you will still see the /## CIDR number after 'Network:', so it goes both ways.

or with [sipcalc](http://www.routemeister.net/projects/sipcalc/):

```
[kbrandt@kbrandt-opadmin: ~] sipcalc 192.168.1.1/24                                                                                             <23403@8:55>
-[ipv4 : 192.168.1.1/24] - 0
[CIDR]
Host address        - 192.168.1.1
Host address (decimal)  - 3232235777
Host address (hex)  - C0A80101
Network address     - 192.168.1.0
Network mask        - 255.255.255.0
Network mask (bits) - 24
Network mask (hex)  - FFFFFF00
Broadcast address   - 192.168.1.255
Cisco wildcard      - 0.0.0.255
Addresses in network    - 256
Network range       - 192.168.1.0 - 192.168.1.255
Usable range        - 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254
```

The Ubuntu Packages are ipcalc and sipcalc:

```
sudo apt-get install ipcalc
sudo apt-get install sipcalc
```

Comment: Interesting output. The ipcalc utility on Fedora (writter by Redhat) is much lamer.

Comment: also whatmask for fedora

Answer (score 5):

[netmask](http://trap.mtview.ca.us/~talby/netmask_2.4.tar.gz) supports automatically figuring out minimal sets of subnets for a particular IP range, which I find to be handy.  For example:

```
# netmask -c 10.32.0.0:10.255.255.255
      10.32.0.0/11
      10.64.0.0/10
     10.128.0.0/9
```

Answer (score 5):

You could [use the bash scripts located here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762575/explanation-of-convertor-of-cidr-to-netmask-in-linux-shell-netmask2cdir-and-cdir) for converting from cidr to mask and mask to cidr notation:

Here's a copy of what the scripts are, to ensure the answer is always available here:

```
mask2cdr ()
{
   # Assumes there's no "255." after a non-255 byte in the mask
   local x=${1##*255.}
   set -- 0^^^128^192^224^240^248^252^254^ $(( (${#1} - ${#x})*2 )) ${x%%.*}
   x=${1%%$3*}
   echo $(( $2 + (${#x}/4) ))
}


cdr2mask ()
{
   # Number of args to shift, 255..255, first non-255 byte, zeroes
   set -- $(( 5 - ($1 / 8) )) 255 255 255 255 $(( (255 << (8 - ($1 % 8))) & 255 )) 0 0 0
   [ $1 -gt 1 ] && shift $1 || shift
   echo ${1-0}.${2-0}.${3-0}.${4-0}
}
```

so for example, running:

`mask2cdr 255.255.255.255` returns `32`

Answer (score 3):

I've used ipcalc before for this.  It looks like Ubuntu also has sipcalc.  See [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=ipcalc&searchon=names&suite=jaunty&section=all).

Answer (score 2):

Try either [sipcalc](http://www.routemeister.net/projects/sipcalc/) or [ipcalc](http://www.jodies.de/ipcalc).

Answer (score 2):

I use ipcalc for network subnetting, but it's limited to IPv4 addresses.
you can use [subnetcalc](http://www.exp-math.uni-essen.de/~dreibh/subnetcalc/), it support both of IPv4 and IPv6.